# Sending and receiving push notification swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

[image]I created a small messenger app using Parse as my database in swift. I wanted each time any user sends a message only other users within 10 meter to get the notification. The app is working but the push notification is not. I did some research it looks like my code is similar to the one i found but still not working. Please help me. Thank you

```
   var CurrentLocation : PFGeoPoint = PFGeoPoint(latitude: 44.6854, longitude: -73.873) // assume the current user is here
            let userQuery = PFUser.query()
           userQuery?.whereKey("Location", nearGeoPoint: CurrentLocation, withinMiles: 10.0)
            let pushQuery = PFInstallation.query()
            pushQuery?.whereKey("username", matchesQuery: userQuery!)
            let push = PFPush()
            push.setQuery(pushQuery) 
            push.setMessage(" New message")
            push.sendPushInBackground()
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What's the error message or is it simply not doing anything? Also go to parse and theres a section there called Logs can you paste the relevant logs here so we can see what's going wrong?

Comment: There is no error but in Parse Push page it shows that the status of the notification Failed. (check the picture on edit)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the line `pushQuery?.whereKey("username", matchesQuery: userQuery!)`. According to the parse docs **Warning: This only works where the key’s values are PFObjects or arrays of PFObjects.** Read more here: https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey:matchesQuery
Instead change it to chain the query by first performing the first query and then using the strings of the userIds for the second query which is performed inside the first's completionBlock.

### Update

Also, just as a side note you are not abiding by the camel case rules of swift and also the rules set out by Parse. You should follow conventions. (See my code for the correct case for keys in Parse and variable names).

Example:

```
var currentLocation : PFGeoPoint = PFGeoPoint(latitude: 44.6854, longitude: -73.873) // assume the current user is here
 let userQuery = PFUser.query()
 userQuery?.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: currentLocation, withinMiles: 10.0) // Note I changed Location to location
userQuery?.findObjectsInBackground({ results, error in
   let usernames = (results as! [PFObject]).map { $0.username }
   let pushQuery = PFInstallation.query()
   pushQuery?.whereKey("username", containedIn: usernames)
   let push = PFPush()
   push.setQuery(pushQuery) 
   push.setMessage("New message")
   push.sendPushInBackground()
})
```

Also note that you may need to change your structure because the docs for PFInstallation.query note that you must use one of three query parameters and you are using none (you might have to save the installation object id to a field on the user. Then instead of making an array with username make an array with the installation object ids and query PFInstallation like that. However, this may still work so try it first, you never know.

Comment: Thank you i fixed it another way but thanks again for help man. I appreciated that